# GWT implement something like a Desktop Icon

Tags: gwt, icons, panel

I have a VerticalPanel consisting of an Image and a Label with some text in it. What I'm trying to implement is something like a Desktop Icon - when you click it - it gets 'marked' and probably a menu will appear. When you click outside of the icon - the menu should disappear and the icon will get unmarked.

Currently I'm trying to achieve this by wrapping the VerticalPanel in a FocusPanel and playing  with some focus handling but I have not achieved any satisfying results so far.

I would appreciate if you could give me some guidance on how to best implement this.

Thanks.

Comment: I would try to use the widget that is made for menus: [MenuBar](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/MenuBar.html) - with a bit of styling, it doesn't have to look like a typical menu/menu bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track with the [FocusPanel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FocusPanel.html) wrapper. The key point about the FocusPanel for what you want to do is that it captures clicks (by implementing [HasClickHandlers](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/HasClickHandlers.html)). You can then handle clicks and assign the panel CSS rules e.g. `border-width`, `border-color`, or `background-color`, etc., according to however you'd like to indicate your icon as pressed/selected.

Comment: Well... okay but what about when I click out of the focus panel? it should then get unselected. how would I implement that?

Comment: You'd add a [BlurHandler](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/BlurHandler.html) since the FocusPanel also implements [HasBlurHandlers](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/HasBlurHandlers.html) and in onBlur() you'd modify your panel's CSS to indicate the loss of selection.

Answer (score 0):

Its seems that you need a [ToggleButton](http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCustomButton) and a basic [PopupPanel](http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwBasicPopup)